# Does MLLib only accept the libsvm data format?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have train set table in Hive .  There are 600 columns and 0~599 columns are features such as age, gender..... and the last column is the label of 0 and 1. 
I read the table as df and the df also has 600 columns.

But I find that in docs in spark(python), the model like random forest and  only accept libsvm format data.

```
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
```

So I wonder whether MLLib only accept libsvm data format ?
If so, how can I transform my dataset to libsvm format, since my dataset is distribution data that stored as hive table.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

if your data is stored in hive , you could read them by spark sql and you get the dataframe, then you can train the dataframe by sqark. The example code could be found [enter link description here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#dataframe)

Comment: The codes in the link use the data format with two columns: label and features, which is different from my data format.

Comment: dataframe could also by saved as libsvm format.   df.write.format("libsvm").save("xxxxxx") .try this

Comment: ```val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
      (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
      (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")        training.write.format("libsvm").save("mylibsvmfile")```